# detectar duplicado php

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas esoty intentando como puedo hacer para quitar duplicados en php o javascript en un textarea quiero insertarle datos
como numeros
ej 
1
1
12
123
y si el numero se repite que se elemine
alguien sabra algo del tema

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y muéstranos el código que has adelantado.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que has hecho hasta ahora para adecuar nuestra respuesta mejor a tu pregunta.